# How to run tests in same browser in parallel using selenium webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

We have set of automated test cases around 2000 and we need to run them daily on every new build that come up. It's currently taking 4 hours to finish the test on one machine. In order reduce this we planning to run tests in batches (500 per batch) on same machine by initiating multiple browsers of same type. Say 4 firefox browser sessions per test suite. So it can finish in 1 hour time.Is it possible to achieve this using selenium webdriver and testng? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using Selenium Grid and TestNG.  Grid can help distribute your tests on various machines or browser instances as you require.  To get started, refer : [Grid2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)
I think you might need to change your driver instantiation code a bit to include RemoteWebDriver instead of concrete drivers, but would be ok if your driver instantiation code in your framework is isolated.  TestNG and Grid can help provided your tests are well written to support parallel execution.
For TestNG, you can refer, [parallel running in TestNG.](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python - the best way to go is to use [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) to drive the tests. To distribute the tests the [pytest-xdist plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) can be used.

Anyway, for both Java and Python you can use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to run/distribute your tests (using [Selenium plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin))